# Plotting proportional frequencies with ggplot2 but leaving out some categories of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a ggplot with proportional frequencies. Here is a reproducible plot:

```
aa <- rep(c("Sta 1", "Sta 2", "Sta 3", "Sta 4"), each = 4)
bb <- rep(c("none", "minimal", "moderate", "major"), 4)                  
cc <- sample(1:40, 16, replace=F)

df <- data.frame(aa,bb,cc)


library(ggplot2)

cols <- c("none" = "light green", "minimal" = "dark green", "moderate" = "light blue", "major" = "dark blue")

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=bb, y = cc, x = aa))
plot + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + scale_colour_manual(values = cols, aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
```

I was asked to leave out the categories "none" and "minimal", but still include the overall proportion. I have a workaround to set the category colors as transparent with NAs:

```
cols <- c("none" = NA, "minimal" = NA, "moderate" = "light blue", "major" = "dark blue")
```

I am not so experienced with this, but am wondering if there is a more elegant solution for leaving out chunks of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

cols <- c("none" = "light green", "minimal" = "dark green", "moderate" = "light blue", "major" = "dark blue")

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=bb, y = cc, x = aa))
plot + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols, aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"),
                      breaks=c('moderate','major'))
```

Output:

[image]

One option can be:

```
#Code 2
plot <- ggplot(subset(df,!bb %in% c("none","minimal")), aes(fill=bb, y = cc, x = aa))
plot + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + scale_colour_manual(values = cols, aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"))
```

Output:

[image]

Or this option:

```
#Code 3
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(fill=bb, y = cc, x = aa))
plot + geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols, aesthetics = c("colour", "fill"),
                      breaks=c('moderate','major'),
                      limits=c('moderate','major'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. I mean to leave the categories of data off the plot and off the legend. So the plot output would just be the "moderate" and "major" bars.

Comment: @crunchypb Just a moment to update the code!

Comment: @crunchypb I have added some options for you. Hope any of them helps you!